# Book I read ~23 years ago about slaves mining something that gave them telepathy

Tags: story-identification, books

After reading through the *Mistborn* series, the slaves mining atium reminded me of a book I read ~23 years ago.

It was about a slave in a mining camp that was forced to mine a mind altering compound that had a side effect of giving the user telepathy.  Pretty sure the mine was on a planet or moon that was otherwise uninhabited and the main character escapes on a space ship of some type.

The book may have been named after an old arcade game, but that might be completely unrelated ... it was a while ago.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Do you remember anything about the cover art or any character or place names?

Comment: Makes me think of the Glitterstim mines in the *Star Wars* EU.

Comment: The Glitterstim mines on Kessel were my first thought as well. *Jedi Search* has Han, Chewie, and Kyp Durron enslaved in the mines for a big chunk of the book and it was published in 1994. The spice they're mining gives people limited telepathy, Kessel is uninhabitable outside the mines, and they eventually steal a ship and escape.

Comment: @DavidW I wish, it was a hard cover w/ no art beyond the title itself (which I cant remember).

Comment: @FuzzyBoots I did read the Han Solo Trillogy back in the day ... and I do remember they messing with some drugs at one point, but that is not the book im trying to remember.  It wasnt based in the starwars universe.

Comment: B. Catling's _[The Vorrh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Vorrh)_ from 2012 has elements of this, but the slaves are affected just by being in the forest they're logging.